# How to include child classes in OQL query in ewam?

Tags: ewam

I have a parent class for eg say A and it has 4 child classes say B,C,D and E. All the child classes are persistent. However, when I write the query as below the child classes are not picked up by my query.

**OQL select * from A using the cursor**

Do I have to write individual query for each child class?

Answer (score 1):

Use of ++
Look through all instances of the class as well as all instances of the class’s decedents. (include all child classes in the search)
  ++

Examples:

```
forEach curCar in OQL select * from x in aVehicle++ 
   where x.Color = cRed
   curCar.Price +=  100
endFor

forEach curPerson in OQL select * from x in aPerson++
   where x.myAddress.City like ‘%New ‘ Order by x.Name
   WriteLn(curPerson)
endFor
```

Please also see wTECH101 day 5 "101A-OQL-Search.pptx" as well as 
eWAM help - search for OQL